# How two make an img fill width in multi-column layout?

Tags: html, css, image, multiple-columns, floating

I'm working on my homepage and I'm trying two get a header with 3 columns.
The first column should be a logo, the second a navigation menu and the third a language switcher.

The nav and the lang. switcher should be align to the right and have auto width (so only the width needed by the content).
The img should be floated to the left and should fill the empty width (!but not bigger than 100% of the img width and with max-height!)

If the browser width gets smaller, than the img should be shrinked, but the right contents should be the same size.

```css
.frame {
  max-width: 90%;
  height: 75px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
#top-header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #CCC;
}
#top-header .frame {
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
}
#top-header .frame div {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
#top-header .frame > div,
nav {
  float: right;
}
#top-header .frame > div:first-child {
  float: left;
  max-width: 60%;
}
#mainmenu {
  position: relative;
  top: 25px;
}
#mainmenu .moduletable {
  display: block;
  position: static;
}
#mainmenu ul.nav.menu {
  display: flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
#mainmenu ul.nav.menu li {
  font-size: .92rem;
  -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  position: relative;
}
#mainmenu ul.nav.menu li a {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header id="top-header">
    <div class="frame">
      <div id="logo">
        <div class="moduletable">
          <div class="custom">
            <p>
              <img alt="logo" src="http://lorempixel.com/1637/100">
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="language-switcher"></div>
      <nav id="mainmenu">
        <div class="moduletable">
          <ul class="nav menu">
            <li class="item-101 current active"> <a href="/home">Home</a>

            </li>
            <li class="item-102 deeper parent"> <a href="/about-us">About us</a>

            </li>
            <li class="item-103"> <a href="#">XXXXXXXX</a>

            </li>
            <li class="item-104"> <a href="#">XXXXXX</a>

            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>
```

Here's an example of my current try at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/azu2mk2p/)

Thanks and have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i understand now.
I changed your layout to work similar to a table with

```
dislpay:table
```

for the `#top-header .frame`

and `dislpay:table-cell`

for the logo and the menu

here is the fixed [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dimshik/azu2mk2p/3/)

Comment: Im sorry, but that's not the right solution for me the problem is, that the mainmenu should not get wider or smaller, it have a fixed width, equal to all its content. I now have changed the logo img in the header: max-height: 50px. Everything is working, if the browser width is big enought. BUT if you shrink the browser window, and there isn't any space between the left logo and the right menu, the menu gets wrapped and the img only scale down, if itself is wider than the parent. But it should shrink if itself + the menu width is bigger than the parent [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/azu2mk2p/2/)

Comment: changed the original answer, i think i got what you tried to do :)
check the jsFiddle link

Comment: Thanks, it looks exactly the way I wanted it.
You really helped me alot!!
I'm gonna test this out...

Comment: But there's another problem I now discovered ....
Could it be, that display: table and display: table-cell dont work on mobile (in my case an iPhone 4)

The img isn't scaling down, so the menu is right off the screen.

It would be cool, if anyone test it on the fiddle